# Custom OpenSSL engine when running within Apache via mod_ssl

Tags: openssl, apache-httpd

I modified my `openssl.cnf` to specify a custom engine for some operations. It works fine if I go through the `openssl` binary directly, but if I load `libssl` from another program it doesn't seem to use that configuration file at all, so my engine isn't available. I ultimately want the engine to be usable from Apache via `mod_ssl`. I think I can use the [`SSLCryptoDevice`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcryptodevice) Apache configuration directive to specify which engine to use, but since it's not reading my OpenSSL configuration, it's not loading my custom engine, so it's not available for use. Is there some way to tell OpenSSL (either directly or, probably, through Apache) to load my engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. If you build `mod_ssl` with `-DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF`, it will load the configuration file the same as the `openssl` binary (I assume the binary is built with the same flag)

Comment: Since it came down to a compile option, what distro are you on?

Comment: @Bratchley Gentoo, although I was building Apache manually anyway